# User is unable to access a site when connected to VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

One of our users is unable to connect to our internal VPN if he is connected to the VPN.

In the TCP/IP settings of the VPN connection, the box for using the remote gateway is unchecked so he is using his local gateway even when connected to the VPN.

However, even with that box unmarked, when he is connected to the VPN and tries to access our SharePoint the computer tries to connect to the site via it's internal instead of the external IP it should be using.

If he tries to go to the page without being connected to the VPN then he can access the internal SharePoint without issue.

Why would his PC be trying to route to the SharePoint using the internal IP when it should be using his local gateway which isn't part of our WAN?

He doesn't have local admin access so it's not like he setup any custom routes or anything of that sort.

Thanks in advance.

Oh, and the user is using the Windows VPN client and Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: How does the user connect to the Sharepoint site, via ip address or FQDN?

Comment: can you clean this up a bit?  There's some discrepancies in here that make it difficult to understand how your Sharepoint is setup (how can he connect to sharepoint _without_ a VPN? Is it published/binded to an external IP address/port?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason for this is if his local subnet and the VPN subnet are the same

Comment: I've been bitten by this before...